# Using Multipeer Connectivity Framework and saving the nearby devices founded

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming, multipeer-connectivity, mobile-development

I am new to Swift and is currently developing an Multipeer Connectivity app for a course project. The app also has an online log-in feature that stores each user information in Firebase(the backend support).

Once the app gets wifi connection, I want to have a 'friends list' feature in my app and add other app users to this list from the nearby devices found. So far, the only way I could think of is to associate the peerID with an existing app user from Firebase. However, according to the documentation, peerID seems to be associated with the device itself so if two different users used the same device to sign in, this approach can't really work. Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it depends on what do you want to go with your application as well as how you develop it regarding your business. One of possibility is that one user as a point of time is just registered one device. So you can provide a simple login screen that users will enter their name then map it with device id and save to Firebase. The username is considered as user id as well. So if they try to sign in from another device, you will check whether or not it existed in the system. if existed, ask them that wish to register this device or not, then update your map (user id and device id) from Firebase.

From your friend list, it is still a list of the username of your friends,in which you can add any nearby devices found.